# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'dxswipestart' of undefined at prod build angular7

Tags: javascript, angular-material, angular7, devextreme

If I do a normal build using *ng build* then not getting this error

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'dxswipestart' of undefined

But when I am doing prod build, getting the above error.

Could anyone please help me on this to resolve an issue?

Comment: Is this error showing during build or runtime? Do you have custom build options for production? Is this error thrown on your code (in this case please post the code snippet) or on some third party library?

Comment: Are you importing a whole additional webpack bundle ? if Yes,  this will causes the production build to stop working because both wepback builds interact similarly with the global scope.